# Flutter exception while building

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

I tried to run/debug my application on the desktop (after installing visual studio 2019 with all defaults) but I can't :) and this error occurred:

```
D:\Visual Studio IDE\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(240,5): error MSB8066: Custom build for 'D:\Location\Some Location\MyFlutterAppLocation\build\windows\CMakeFiles\a50fa560346c71769b697565b5a2d59b\flutter_windows.dll.rule;D:\Location\MyFlutterAppLocation\build\windows\CMakeFiles\eb8cecdef0b53de6eb232004d53dfd8a\flutter_assemble.rule' exited with code 1. [D:\Location\Some Location\MyFlutterAppLocation\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
Exception: Build process failed.
```

Comment: Should be running VS Code not Visual Studio 2019 (https://code.visualstudio.com). Please update the question to reflect the current environment.

Comment: You need to install the 'desktop development with c++' plugin in visual studio, not just visual studio.

Comment: @TommieC. I run my flutter project on VS Code, not Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: @AbdelrahmanSherif I have installed them, if you don't install desktop development with c++, flutter doesn't let you run your project.

Answer (score 5):

- Few times when I faced a `.vcxproj error`, I had a previously built .exe process running, even after closing it. I ended the .exe via task manager and the issue was solved. You can spot the running build using the flutter icon or the supplied app icon.
- In another instance, I faced a similar error after I interrupted previous `flutter run`. In this case, I wasn't able to spot the .exe as it wasn't completely built. I don't know which process is specifically using `.vcxproj`. Hence I resorted to a cleaning of the project:

  ```
  flutter clean
  flutter create --platforms=windows,web,android .
  flutter run
  ```

  Though this second case doesn't pinpoint the source of the error, I was happy to have solved it without restarting VSCode or signing out of windows.